# Error in an after hook, PG::InFailedSqlTransaction from Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems

I was trying to run rspec from a model spec file, but I got this error: "An error occurred in an after hook"

> "An error occurred in to after hook  PG :: InFailedSqlTransaction:
>   ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of
>   transaction. occurred at C :/ Ruby193/lib/.../postgresql_adapter: 294 "

I googled this issue, and I found a suggestion to downgrade my 'database_cleaner' to '1.0.1'. I did, but it doesn't work.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22):

This can happen if you execute a bad SQL statement in the scope of a transaction, you rescue the exception from that statement, and then try and execute another SQL statement in the same transaction.

Once one statement in a transaction fails no more statements can be executed in that transaction.

Here's an example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  begin
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "A bad query"
  rescue => ex 
    puts ex.message
  end
  puts User.count
end
```

`User.count` raises `PG::InFailedSqlTransaction` because the previous SQL statement raised `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` and that was swallowed by the `rescue`.

So I would look for code that rescues in the scope of a transaction and then tries to run additional SQL statements.

Comment: this error happens to me in ActiveRecord callback, If I understand correctly, all callbacks are wrapped in one transaction, how to identify which one is the root cause? ( meanwhile I check the source code, and didn't find `rescue` in the source code)

Comment: @Ryan Lyu Did you find any solution?